# Validate nested array as per other array value in FormRequest

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

Assuming that I have the below validation, which is an extract on my validation FormRequest. How could I declare my validations to make `Rule::requiredIf` work?

```php
public function rules()
{
        return [
            ....
            'sections.*.content.*.type' => [
                'required',
            ],
            'sections.*.content.*.categories' => [
                Rule::requiredIf('sections.*.content.*.type' == 'category'),
                'array'
            ],
            'sections.*.content.*.banners' => [
                Rule::requiredIf('sections.*.content.*.type' == 'banner'),
                'array'
            ]
        ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of cases, I would recommend to use a custom validation to have cleaner code but if you would like to use `Rule::requiredIf`, it can be used with the closure like the example below to achieve what you have asked.

```
Rule::requiredIf(function () {
    return request()->input('sections.*.content.*.type') === 'banner';
})
```